# Prove that a specific map induces an embedding from $\mathbb{R}P^{2}$ into $\mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Can someone help me:

The map $f : {S}^2  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^6$ given by $f (x; y; z) = (x^2, y^2, z^2, \sqrt{2}yz, \sqrt{2}xz, \sqrt{2}xy)$ induces an embedding $C^{\infty}$ of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$?

How can we get from $f$ a embedding $C^{\infty}$ of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: It is called the Veronese mapping. See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/139234

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).